# How to find specific multi-variable thresholds for AUC cutpoint?

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, logistic-regression, auc

I want to figure out how to find the variable cutoff points for a glm. Cutpointr does this really well for single variable but with more complex models how would I go about extracting this info? Say I did ~ glucose + age + mass and wanted at this cutoff values x, y and z are present or is this not possible? would it be more like this number is the summed cutoff of the variables? Also sorry for no images it wouldn't let me add them in!

```r
#for reprex
library(reprex)
library(mlbench)     
library(tidymodels)
library(cutpointr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'cutpointr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:yardstick':
#> 
#>     accuracy, npv, ppv, precision, recall, sensitivity, specificity
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

data(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)
head(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)
#>   pregnant glucose pressure triceps insulin mass pedigree age diabetes
#> 1        6     148       72      35      NA 33.6    0.627  50      pos
#> 2        1      85       66      29      NA 26.6    0.351  31      neg
#> 3        8     183       64      NA      NA 23.3    0.672  32      pos
#> 4        1      89       66      23      94 28.1    0.167  21      neg
#> 5        0     137       40      35     168 43.1    2.288  33      pos
#> 6        5     116       74      NA      NA 25.6    0.201  30      neg

Diabetes <- na.omit(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)
glimpse(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)
#> Rows: 768
#> Columns: 9
#> $ pregnant <dbl> 6, 1, 8, 1, 0, 5, 3, 10, 2, 8, 4, 10, 10, 1, 5, 7, 0, 7, 1, 1…
#> $ glucose  <dbl> 148, 85, 183, 89, 137, 116, 78, 115, 197, 125, 110, 168, 139,…
#> $ pressure <dbl> 72, 66, 64, 66, 40, 74, 50, NA, 70, 96, 92, 74, 80, 60, 72, N…
#> $ triceps  <dbl> 35, 29, NA, 23, 35, NA, 32, NA, 45, NA, NA, NA, NA, 23, 19, N…
#> $ insulin  <dbl> NA, NA, NA, 94, 168, NA, 88, NA, 543, NA, NA, NA, NA, 846, 17…
#> $ mass     <dbl> 33.6, 26.6, 23.3, 28.1, 43.1, 25.6, 31.0, 35.3, 30.5, NA, 37.…
#> $ pedigree <dbl> 0.627, 0.351, 0.672, 0.167, 2.288, 0.201, 0.248, 0.134, 0.158…
#> $ age      <dbl> 50, 31, 32, 21, 33, 30, 26, 29, 53, 54, 30, 34, 57, 59, 51, 3…
#> $ diabetes <fct> pos, neg, pos, neg, pos, neg, pos, neg, pos, pos, neg, pos, n…

cp <- cutpointr(Diabetes, glucose, diabetes, 
                method = maximize_metric, metric = sum_sens_spec)
#> Assuming the positive class is pos
#> Assuming the positive class has higher x values

plot_cutpointr(cp)

summary(cp)
#> Method: maximize_metric 
#> Predictor: glucose 
#> Outcome: diabetes 
#> Direction: >= 
#> 
#>     AUC   n n_pos n_neg
#>  0.8058 392   130   262
#> 
#>  optimal_cutpoint sum_sens_spec    acc sensitivity specificity tp fn fp  tn
#>               128        1.5055 0.7628      0.7231      0.7824 94 36 57 205
#> 
#> Predictor summary: 
#>     Data Min.   5% 1st Qu. Median     Mean 3rd Qu.    95% Max.       SD NAs
#>  Overall   56 81.0   99.00  119.0 122.6276  143.00 181.00  198 30.86078   0
#>      neg   56 79.0   94.00  107.5 111.4313  126.00 154.00  197 24.64213   0
#>      pos   78 95.9  124.25  144.5 145.1923  171.75 188.55  198 29.83939   0

res_unnested <- cp %>% 
  unnest(cols = roc_curve)

annotation <- paste0("AUC: ", round(cp$AUC, 2), "\n", 
                     "Cutpoint: ", round(cp$optimal_cutpoint, 2))

ggplot(res_unnested, aes(x = 1 - tnr, y = tpr)) +
  xlab("1 - Specificity") +
  ylab("Sensitivity") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  geom_line(color = "red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1 - cp$specificity, linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = cp$sensitivity, linetype = "dotted") +
  annotate("text", x = 0.85, y = 0.05, label = annotation) +
  ggtitle("ROC curve",  "Using glucose mg/dL as a predictive logistic variable for diabetes") + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = 2)

ROC(form = diabetes ~ glucose + age + mass, data=Diabetes, plot = "ROC", MX = T)
```

I have tried to add more parameters to cutpointr which was unsuccessful. I have also tried to run with Epi and saw a better AUC with age and mass included. I have also run a glm but I am just not sure how to properly analyze the glm for this type of information. Looking on the tidymodels website for help while waiting for suggestions, thanks!

Comment: This seems to be more of a question about model fitting and interpretation rather than a specific programming question. If you need statistical advice or recommendations, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. Find out what method you want to use first, then see how that method is implemented in R.

Comment: The probability of diabetes, and the optimum cutoff, will be a function of the three predictor variables.  For example, if you take two people with a glucose of 100, then the combination of age = 50, mass = 43 would give a 50:50 probability of diabetes, but so would age =60, mass = 36. There are an infinite combination of the three variables that could give the same probability of diabetes. You can calculate the probability of diabetes given any set of values from running a glm and using `predict`.

Comment: that makes sense @AllanCameron thank you! so if I were have a column that added those variables together in cutpointr it would be the same idea that this threshold of combined variables is the cutoff point? your example really helped me wrap my head around it!

Comment: @MrFlick i definitely need to learn more in those area's as well, just was curious if this function could be outputted in the mentioned packages. because even now understanding the comment about additive variables being interchangeable I am not sure how to find this information in the glm/add to a roc curve. however I think it may be more helpful for me to visit the linked community as it seems pretty informative first, thank you!

Comment: @mickmars51 no, you can't just add the values together. You need to multiply each by its glm coefficient to get the appropriate weights. When you add _those_ together you will have something that will work in `cutpointr`